# How to suddenly stop DC gear motor, after certain revolutions?

Tags: dc-motor

If a DC motor is moving at 100-200 RPM and if I wanna stop it suddenly. 
IS there any way to stop it quickly ?

I'm using H-bridge to provide current to the motor?
I tried to reverse it for a while and then ground both the terminals. In this way motor suddenly stops and then moves forward. If I'm increasing reverse time then moves backward?

I tried to use reverse-forward, reverse-forward then grounding both the controlling bits ( of micro-controller) but still prob not solved ...

Comment: Why are you asking us about how you are providing current to the motor? We certainly don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answer is far more detailed, a simpler solution would be to use a stepper motor. You can stop at an exact step, but if you need high speeds you would need some sort of system built around it.

DC motors aren't particularly precise, and H-Bridges only help marginally. Stepper motors move in exact increments.

Comment: YEah, stepper motor moves exact to the given position, but I wanna to stop DC gear motor rather stepper or servo.

Comment: What do you think a servo is? It IS a DC gear motor, with an H-Bridge tracking position.

Comment: YES, it is. I'm using DC motors to move robotics base. I want to stop it suddenly as it detects any obstacle on the path.

Comment: The best way to quickly halt a motor without some external mechanical systems would be electrical braking. Short the motor's contacts together.